# How to split an icon into 3 different objects?

Tags: inkscape

I have converted the following image using trace bitmap, to a vector.

[image]

Now what i want to is break this object in such a way that the 2 hands and the circle are separate paths, so in total 3 paths. I need this as i want to move the hands around a little bit, so far what i have done is , converted the object to a path using `path -> object to path` , after this i tried many options like the node tool , then select all nodes and break apart but i am getting weird results.

So far when i select all the nodes , my object looks like so:

[image]

So how exactly do i go about splitting this path into 3 different objects(I am not sure i am phrasing this right) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. In Inkscape select the logo and click `Path` > `Break Apart`.
2. The result will be a solid circle, but the paths are still there.  With the `Edit Paths by Nodes` tool  select both the outer and inner paths of the circle, by dolding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking, to make a multiple selection, and click `Path` > `Combine`.
3. Now select both paths that form the inner and outer parts of the top hand in the same way, and click `Path` > `Combine`.
4. Do the same for the outer and inner path of the lower hand.

That's it! Now all three parts of the logo are separate.

[image: Illustrated steps]